# libc/libcstdc++ issue - GLIBC_2.18 not found

Tags: debian, libraries, postgis, libc6

After some package update on my Debian (Sid) machine I started to experience errors like:

Error message from server: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/postgis-1.5.so": /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)

It mainly happens when I'm trying to perform some queries on Postgres 9.1 database with PostGIS 1.5.

How can I resolve this? Downgrading libc6 and libcstdc++ packages didn't help.

Comment: What exactly did you update?

Comment: You're running unstable. Stop doing that.

Comment: is there a way to display update history?

Comment: Did you reboot? :)

Comment: No, I didn't. Will it help? It's a remote machine, far away.

Comment: I have this exact problem but only with 32 bit programs.

Comment: I solved this problem by upgrading libstdc++.so.6. You can either use package manager or find a higher version of libstdc++.